# Docker-compose start scaled services sequentially, so instance port maps to host ports in order?

Tags: selenium, docker-compose

I have built a web scraping service with Selenium docker container, running several instances via docker-compose.
Every now and then I want to see the content of screen for debugging purpose.
So I exposed the vnc port (5900) of Selenium instance, to be mapped to a range of ports on the host machine like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: mylocalapp
  sel:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
      - "10001-10010:5900"
```

Then I can have required number of selenium instances (up to 10 in the above example) via command:

```
docker-compose up -d --scale sel=5
```

I can successfully connect to instance port 5900 from a VNC client, on host ports 10000-10009.
But the problems with this approach is that, there is no easy way to tell which port is mapped to each container.

I can `docker ps` to check which port is mapped to which instance, but the order is often confusing because `sel` instances initialise in a random order.
(sel_1 is 10004, sel_2 is 10001... etc)

It'd be a lot easier for me to manage, if all `sel` instance initialise in sequential order, so sel_1 is 10001, sel_2 is 10002... etc.

Is there a way to start `sel` instances sequentially, so that `sel_2` waits for `sel_1`, then `sel_3`, `sel_4`... ?

Comment: Can you give an example of how would that help you to manage containers and perform debugging?

Comment: when I have container name and host ports arranged in sequential order, I can quickly connect to that exact instance via VNC client, because I'd know sel_1 is port 10001, sel_5 is 10005, etc. Currently I need to click open them all, a bit of a lottery because I have no easy way of knowing which instance is mapped to which host port. I am debugging from a remote machine, docker-compose cluster running on another server.